# Android Library Project on Jenkins with Gradle

Tags: android, maven, jenkins, gradle

I am new to gradle. I am trying to integrate an android project which is built with maven on jenkins to gradle. I have two projects, one of them is a library project which is developed by me and the other one is the app, which uses this library project.

It can be done on Android Studio with `compile project(':XXX')` but don't know how to do it on Jenkins.

Any help appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Any solution yet on this?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I could solve the problem by defining the library project as submodule of my project.